# I can't seem to find the conflict while loading jquery plugin dependencies

Tags: jquery, validation, dependencies, conflict

I cannot seem to find my jquery dependency plugin conflict. CURL.js loads the jquery validation plugin, jquery form plugin and css perfectly every time without throwing errors in firebug.  When I click the submit button jquery form plugin does not use ajax to submit the form, instead it submits normally when I follow these steps:

1)Click Register link

2)Click Shopper link and wait for it to load

3)Click Store link and wait for it to load

4)Again click Shopper link and wait for it to load

5)Click the submit button

The steps can be vise versa also.

However, if I click one of the links and do not click the second link, then press the submit button, jquery validation triggers correctly; once the form passes validation the form plugin submits the form using ajax.

Demo link: http://www.dickschicks.net/demo/

Please let me know if the demo link is not enough and that you need more information to further assist me.

Comment: That link doesn't lead to what you're describing - there are no Shopper or Store links

Comment: please click the register in the top nav bar. that should load the shopper and store link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that each click of the Shopper or Store links replaces the contents of the form with a new set of html.  But only the first click of each loads the validation scripts.

So the second time you click back to Shopper, it doesn't run your scripts again, and the original `#shopperJoinForm` and it's validator have been removed.  Now you just have a blank form.

I don't really understand what the curl thing is supposed to be doing... but what I'm thinking is that you move your validation calls into a function like this (this would be in the `shopper_validation.js`:

```
function setupValidation(){
  $("#shopperJoinForm").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
     //all the rest of your validate setup
  });
}
```

Then back in your `join.js`, have it check whether that function exists, call it if it does, and if not, do your curl thing.
The

Comment: curl loads .js and .css files that are needed. for more information check out https://github.com/cujojs/curl/wiki i will implement your idea tomorro.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it loads the files, I'm just not clear on how they would prefer you to use it - it seems to me that they want you to load "modules", but your code is more just a collection of statements...